# TypeScript Support for EmberJS, AngularJS or BatmanJS

Tags: angularjs, ember.js, typescript

Will TypeScript support any of those great MV* frameworks.

I know it's too early to ask this, but what about the chances to reach support for them with this young javascript initiative?

Comment: I think you ask for definitions files, I'm confident they will be done for all main javascript frameworks, it's not so much work

Comment: As I understand it, you can use the compiler to get a head start on a definition file. See here (shameless self-promotion): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12722039/is-there-a-typescript-interface-definition-for-the-facebook-javascript-sdk/12724383#12724383

Answer (score 12, accepted):

TypeScript already supports these and every other JavaScript library. Any JavaScript code is valid TypeScript code.

Obviously to see any benefits from TypeScript these libraries would need to add type annotations, this can be done unobtrusively by creating Declaration Source Files (files with a `.d.ts` extension). These are basically header files that describe the type information associated with existing JavaScript code.

It is obviously outside the scope of the TypeScript project to create these Declaration Source Files for every popular JavaScript library. It is up to those projects and the community to contribute this.

You can view [a sample Declaration Source File for jQuery](http://typescript.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/fe3bc0bfce1f#samples/jquery/jquery.d.ts) that is included in the TypeScript samples.

Comment: Go on the discussion forums for those projects and propose helping to create the declaration files.

Comment: Thanks so much
Anyway I keep thinking about the JSON-Like way to emulate model classes used in EmberJS for example, due to the TypeScript prototype-like way to compile classes.

Answer (score 11):

[DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped) has already covered most (if not all) of mv* JavaScript frameworks.
They have definitions for angularjs, backbone, ember, knockout and more.
Check it out.

Comment: This is a broken link.  This link works: https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped

Answer (score 6):

1. All JavaScript is TypeScript.
2. MV* frameworks are JavaScript.
3. Therefore, MV* frameworks are TypeScript.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an interesting article talking about TypeScript and AngularJS

http://www.piotrwalat.net/using-typescript-with-angularjs-and-web-api/