# Is there a TypeScript interface definition for the Facebook JavaScript SDK

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk, typescript

The TypeScript package contains interface definitions for Node.js and jQuery. I was wondering if somebody has already wrote definitions for Facebook JavaScript SDK.

Comment: Take a look at http://github.com/mientjan/typescript-facebook-definition, it has a definition file for the facebook sdk. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can get it with [tsd](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/tsd) by typing `tsd install fbsdk --save`. Here it is in Definitely Typed: https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/fbsdk/fbsdk.d.ts

(From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29463433/496046))

Answer (score 0):

No, not officially produced or supported. But if the community creates one, we would be happy to link to & promote as required.