# Using Facebook SDK from typescript

Tags: javascript, facebook, typescript

In my web app I am using Typescript and want to use FB sdk functions example: `api`, `login` etc from Typescript.

When compiling my typescript code that uses FB.init(), I get the following errors:

```
Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.
Cannot find name 'FB'.
```

Comment: this is not too broad! this is a massive headache with a simple solution (I don't know what the solution is but I know it's simple!)

Comment: Nominated to reopen

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use existing type definitions : https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/fbsdk/fbsdk.d.ts

For an example of usage look at the tests: 
https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/fbsdk/fbsdk-tests.ts

`api` and `login` are defined: https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/fbsdk/fbsdk.d.ts#L103-L114

**UPDATE (Dec 2016)**

The new repository is:

https://github.com/retyped/fbsdk-tsd-ambient

**UPDATE (Apr 2018)**

https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/facebook-js-sdk/index.d.ts

Comment: Search nuget for the Facebook definitely typed typings.

Comment: Add types from npm - https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/facebook-js-sdk.

Comment: Does anyone know how to get Typescript to recognize the global FB? I've installed facebook-js-sdk as a dev dependency and added it to my list of eslint globals, but it still doesn't recognize FB.

Comment: @Colin Add "facebook-js-sdk" to "types" section in tsconfig.json

Comment: try using `window.FB` instead of simply `FB`